# How to create Pivot from selection, in VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I tried analyzing how Excel creates a pivot from a selection. It seems pretty simple. I select the entire range in my document and hit Create Pivot with that range. That produces the following code:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Keyword report!R2C1:R643841C25", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet38!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

I want to use this code in the future, but instead of using a fixed reference to a particular range, I want Excel to draw that data from the Selection. For some reason, that's not included by the Macro Record. I have no idea what "R2C1:R643841C25" is or how it is derived. My selection is: A1:Y643841.

The big question: How do I replace R2C1:R643841C25 in the code with the "Selection"?

Comment: Please write that as an answer, I would like to give you best answer. :)

Comment: Deleted and added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An understanding of [R1C1 notation](https://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/) would help you answer this.

Comment: That it did. Now I just have to figure out how to pass that information into PivotCaches.Create. Should be easy. :)